# How can I undo my last git add

Tags: git

Just curious to know. Say I have one file named test, I add `Hello World\n` to the file and `git add` it.

Now in the staging area, there should be a file named test with content `Hello World\n`.

Now I add another line `Hello World 2\n` and then `git add` it.

Now my staging area would be file test with its content as "Hello World\nHello World2\n".

Now is there any way that I undo my second git-add to make the staging area back to file test with content "Hello World\n".

Assumptions: There may or may not be any commits at this time. Please consider two conditions.

Additions: What if there are multiple git-add and I want to undo the last n times of them.

Comment: As far as I’m aware, nothing keeps track of `git add`’s history. (Which makes sense – commits are for keeping track of history.) You’ll probably have to do it manually, which isn’t really an undo. (That is, unstage and `git add -p`, then split or edit as necessary.)

Comment: .git/objects records all the changes you made. Every time you git add sth, git will create a corresponding blob object and you can "git cat-file -p" to view the change. What I need is a way to manage staging index more straight forward instead of using interactive modes. Hope there is one :)

Answer (score 3):

Once you do a `git add`, Git starts to track the file and creates a SHA-1 **every time** you add a file to the staging area.

You can recover and restore any of the versions you had in the staging area as long as `git gc` did not compact and clean your repository.

Assuming you didn’t run `git gc`, you simply need to know the SHA-1 of your file.

#### What happens when I add the same file to the staging area again?

Once you add the same file to stash with new contents, Git calculates the new SHA-1 for the file and updates the tree with the new SHA-1. The old SHA-1 is still stored under `.git/objects`.

#### How do I restore the “old” staged file?

First you need to find the SHA-1 of the desired file.

```
# print the list of all the dangling files in the repo
git fsck

# now you need to manually search the files to find the desired 
# "old file" and then restore it using git cat-file -p
```

[image: Screenshot]

---

#### A complete example:

```
cd tmp
mkdir repo1
cd repo1
git init
echo 'line1' > a.txt
git add .
echo 'line2' >> a.txt
git add .
git fsck
git cat-file -p a29bdeb434d874c9b1d8969c40c42161b03fafdc
git cat-file -p c0d0fb45c382919737f8d0c20aaf57cf89b74af8
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can find the SHA-1 of an "older" version, but "git cat-file" just provide content/type/size info for repository objects, which means it doesn't change or unstage anything. What kind of command could I use to manipulate content in the staging area? I know "git reset -i" will let me manually manage which part to unstage. Is there any more efficient way to make the work more straight forward, like change the file to a specific "older" SHA-1 with a few commands?

Comment: Thanks. Your answer answered something I should have known before answering a question incorrectly. I can't find that question from yesterday, but it had to do with a file being re-edited, and before the commit.

Answer (score 1):

The stage doesn't save individual actions, it just keeps the state of the files. Therefore, if you do multiple adds, you just see the result in the stage, not a series of actions.

Git itself tells you how to revert the staged changes:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   blah.txt
```